# Como passar uma query para Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou a tentar traduzir uma *`SQL`* para `Eloquent`, em que ela recebe um id (`$myid`) e retorna as combinações da roupa, ou seja, tenho uma tabela *`clothes`* e tenho outra tabela *`combinations_clothes`* e neste caso fiquei com uma relação *`many to many`*.

A tabela `combinations_clothes` é constituída da seguinte forma:

```
Schema::create('combinations_clothes', function (Blueprint $table) 
{
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('clothe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('clothe_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('clothes')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('combination_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('combination_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('clothes')->onDelete('cascade');
}
```

Para tal, criei uma *`SQL`* para me retornar as combinações da roupa (`$myid`), independentemente da ordem com que foi grudada, ou seja `clothe_id = 2` e `combination_id = 5` é o mesmo que ter sido gravado `clothe_id = 5` e `combination_id = 2` e a *SQL* é a seguinte:

```
select 'clothes.id´ from clothes join 'combinations_clothes´
where (clothes.id = clothe_id or clothes.id = combination_id)
        and clothes.id <> $myid
```

No entanto, precisava passar essa *SQL* para `Eloquent` do `Laravel`. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Você tem as duas classes?

Comment: Tenho apenas a class clothes. Uma vez que que é uma relação many to many entre a mesma tabela 'clothes', usei a model clothes e criei os métodos da relação many to many dentro desta.

Comment: Aquele resposta é um comentário, se pode colocar aqui ou direto na sua pergunta, disponibilize a classe `Clothes` e se tiver relação elas também!